# Value is undefined returning model in JS Odoo POS

Tags: javascript, xml, odoo, odoo-10

I'm trying to overwrite Orderline price in POS Odoo

**My price.js**

```
get_unit_display_price: function(){
    var self = this;                
    var line = self.export_as_JSON();
    var product = this.pos.db.get_product_by_id(line.product_id);        
    fields.product_id  = line.product_id;
    fields.pricelist_id   = this.pos.config.pricelist_id[0];
    fields.uom = product.uom_id;
    fields.line_qty = line.qty;
    fields.price_unit = line.price_unit;
    var model = new Model('pos.order');
     this.total_price = model.call('calculate_price',
            [0, fields]).done(function(result){
                 total_price = result['total_price'];
                 return  result['total_price'];
            });

}
```

**price.xml**

```
    <t t-jquery=".price" t-operation="append">      
        <t t-esc="widget.format_currency(line.get_unit_display_price)"/>
    </t>
```

I'm getting value **total_price** from Model (price.py)
But returning is **undefined** in get_unit_display_price in xml file.

How to set value in xml from js after execution of new model function (js value from model) ?.

Answer (score 0):

There are many problem in your code, i can list some:

1. In your price.js which extends Orderline model, you called function "caculate_price" from backend => it's asynchronous function, so i can't return value for you immediately => your function return `undefined` before the call success
2. You don't need `export_as_JSON()`, you can get value you want (field: product_id, uom, qty, price_unit) directly from Orderline object.
3. In your "price.xml", you want to call a function from model, you missed parenttheses, it should be like this `line.get_unit_display_price()`.

> How to set value in xml from js after execution of new model function
>   (js value from model) ?.

There are 2 options:

- Option 1: call method of py file on server via `rpc`, then wait for response result as you did (i don't recommend this way). So when the call has done, you should get a DOM where value should display in HTML, then update value to it.
- Option 2: i recommend you implement an method "calculate_price" which will do same logic as server in `Orderline` model, so your POS can work without the internet (semi-offline mode). Then you can easy call it from xml file. It means you write function `calculate_price` in your `price.js` then call it in `get_unit_display_price`

Hope it help, i hope you will do option 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
get_orderline: function() {
    var order = this.pos.get_order();
    var orderlines = order.orderlines.models;
    var all_lines = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < orderlines.length; i++) {
        var line = orderlines[i]
        if (line) {
            all_lines.push({
                'product_id': line.product.id,
                'qty': line.quantity,
                'price': line.get_display_price(),
            })
        }
    }
    return all_lines
},
```